# Cannot select cloned elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, clone

After cloning a select element and incrementing the "name" attribute, I am unable to select the cloned elements.

For example:

HTML

```
<select name="1"></select>

<select name="1-1"></select> <!-- cloned element -->
<select name="1-2"></select> <!-- cloned element -->
```

JS

```
$('[name^="1"]').change(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

When I change the original element, it works fine I get the alert, but when I change one of the cloned elements, nothing happens. There are no errors.

Note: I am using "name" attribute instead of ID because I need to retrieve these cloned element values once the form is submitted

Should this work?? or is it that the cloned elements cant be selected?

Comment: When I inspect element the cloned elements have the correct name

Comment: If you're adding elements dynamically after the page has been loaded, wire up the event listeners with live() or delegate(). Normal handlers are bound when the code is run at page load, so if you're cloning after that point, there won't be handlers for the new elements.

Comment: yep the elements are being cloned after the page load. Im not really sure how to use live or delegate

Comment: Do I add the live method to the cloned elements? How do I do this if I dont know that they will exist?

Comment: It functions like bind, so it can be used on elements that already exist or ones that will exist, because behind the scene it's not bound directly to the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the doc link for [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)<sup>DOC</sup> and here's the one for [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)<sup>DOC</sup>

```
$('[name^=1]').live('change', function(){
  console.log('hi!');
});
```

Although it functions differently than a regular event handler (it's actually listening for events on the document, so it "handles" the event on propagation. Delegate is a little more efficient because you give it a context to listen on:

```
$('form').delegate('select[name^=1]', 'change', function(){
  console.log('hi there!');
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, when you do the clone passing the parameter "true" will cause it to also clone the events assigned to the previous object. $(this).clone(true)

Comment: This is true. If you only need the events already bound to the originals, that would be syntactically cleaner. live() and delegate() in this context are more useful for different event listeners you may want to attach.